# Where can I read Hanuman charitam in English?

Tags: scripture, ramayana, hanuman, translation-request

Where can I read Hanuman charitam in English?
Is there any online pdf?

Comment: Is Hanuman Charitam another book?

Comment: @Archit Yes, it is written by Parashara the father of Vyasa.

Comment: @Archit oh thanks a lot 

Comment: @Archit thanks.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.jayahanumanji.com/?p=2091 here chapter 1 to chapter 40.
http://www.jayahanumanji.com/?p=3295 here chapter 41 till 68

right now this much has been translated